# Notepad++ Regex Issue - Remove Number in Line Replace with HTML

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm a regex newbie so this has been a lot of trial and error but for some reason I can only get this to work sometimes and I'm not sure why.  Let me layout what I'm doing.  I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1.Some Text Here  
A paragraph of words here.

2.Some More Text Here  
A paragraph of words here.
```

I use this code to find the lines with a number at the beginning:

```
^[0-9]+.([^.]*)$
```

Then I replace it with this:

```
<h2>$1</h2>\r\r
```

The problem I'm running into is that it usually grabs the line starting with the number but for some reason it will grab the line with the number and the paragraph below it.  So instead of putting the `</h2>` at the end of the line it puts it at the end of the paragraph below.

I displayed all symbols to see if it had something to do with carriage/line returns but everything looks identical from line to line.  The paragraph is on its own line and I see CRLF at the end of each line.

Comment: Please provide some example input on which the regex doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: `[^.]*` tells the engine to match _everything_ until it finds the next dot or end_of_string (file?). So, its no surprise it matches your sample text. Basically you need `^\d+\..*` and it just matches the remainder of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `[^.]` (ie not a literal dot) matches newlines.

Don't match newlines in your capture:

```
^[0-9]+\.([^.\r\n]*)
```

Note that I also escaped the dot following the numbers, making it match a *literal* dot (a naked dot matches *any* character).

Answer (score 0):

use `\2` instead of `$2`, check "wrap around"
tested on notepad++ 5.9.3 (UNICODE)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of notepad++ you're using but your version of the regex works fine for the example that you have ... i use 6.7.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce with the following text. Notice the paragraph for line 1 doesn't end in a period.

```
1.Some Text Here[CR][LF]
A paragraph of words here[CR][LF]

2.Some Text Here[CR][LF]
A paragraph of words here.[CR][LF]
```

Your regex matches any number of lines that begins with a set of digits, and doesn't end in a period. It could include more than one line. I would recommend this regex: `^[0-9]+\.([^\r\n]*)\r\n`.